# React For loop component

Tags: react.js, jsx

This is my React component for looping a component i.e. I don't want to use `MAP` or `FOREACH` in React Component's HTML.

```
import React from 'react';

/**
 * @param {items} from props
 * @description -> Works with array of items and render only one children object inside it, ith data object will be available in children component props.
 */

const RFor = (props) => {
    const { items } = props || [];
    return items.map((data, index) => <div key={index}>{React.cloneElement(props.children, data)}</div>)
}

export default RFor;
```

And this is how I use to iterate my component.

```
<RFor items={TEMP_DATA_ARRAY}>
              <Item />
            </RFor>
```

What this will do is generate `<Item />` till `TEMP_DATA_ARRAY` and each object is going to be available with `data` property inside `<Item />`.
I want to optimize it and this is the best approach I can come up with.

Answer (score 3):

This approach is not bad but I'd highlight a few issues:

- You wrap each element with a `<div>`, it's unnecessary and for a very long list you create many useless elements. This also prevents `<RFor>` to be conveniently used (for example) to generate rows in a table.
- You're assigning `data` to the properties of each item. While this might be convenient it's also fragile: what if an object as a property named `key`, or `children`, `ref` or...anything else already used? I'd assign `data` to a single property.
- `const { items } = props || []` does not do what you, probably, think it's doing. `[]` won't be the default if `items` is falsy but the default if `props` is falsy. The correct syntax, if the value is `undefined` is `const { items = [] } = props;`. If you want to handle also `null` then you can't destructure: `const items = props.items || [];`.
- To use index as `key` is, more often than not, a terrible idea if the list isn't fixed (for example if you can remove/add elements anywhere in the list). Leave this responsibility to the *caller* because it's the only one with enough knowledge to pick a sensible unique ID (which in *some very specific cases* can even be the index).
- You're passing `props.children` directly to `React.cloneElement` however it expects a single element and `children` can be an array. Enforce this rule using `React.only()`.

To put things together (leaving out the `key` for the moment):

```
const RFor = props => {
    const items = props.items || [];
    return items.map(data => React.cloneElement(React.only(props.children), { data });
};
```

All these said you may start wondering if you even need `RFor`, let's compare with few alternatives:

```
<RFor items={TEMP_DATA_ARRAY}>
    <Item />
<RFor>
```

Vs

```
{TEMP_DATA_ARRAY.map(data => <Item key={data.id} {...data} />)}
```

Or:

```
{TEMP_DATA_ARRAY.map(data => <Item key={data.id} data={data} />)}
```

I don't see any benefit (note that you may, instead of `children` use a property like:

```
<RFor items={TEMP_DATA_ARRAY} component={Item} />
```

Also note that to solve the `key` problem you might use a render function:

```
<RFor items={TEMP_DATA_ARRAY}>
    {data => <Item key={data.key} data={data} />}
<RFor>
```

`RFor` IMHO makes sense only if it adds any other value over `map()`, it might be filtering or it might be part of an abstraction to build a *presentation* component with *templates* (with properties like `controlTemplate`, `headerTemplate` and `itemTemplate` as you often see in WPF).

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer. I really appreciate it.
Well, RFor is just made for abstraction! And you can clearly see the difference between the code you wrote with RFor vs Map. RFor is much readable.
Anyway thanks.

Comment: Hmmmm well, if there isn't any other added value then I don't _feel_ it's any more readable than a plain simple `map()` (especially because you REALLY have to address the `key` issue then you probably end-up with a render function) but that just my personal POV (even if I appreciate the `dom-repeat` thing in Polymer).